# Use of Git for a Code Tutorial Site

Tags: git

I want to make an instructional site which contains a series of blog posts trying to program a project. The goal of each blog post is to take a bite-sized chunk of the problem and solve it, producing the code step-by-step.

I would like to provide the code for the reader, so that they could, say, download the code that we completed before post #3 and work from there. Thus, each blog post has its own set of code, building on previous sets of code.

It seems to me that this basically reflects how git commits work - as I complete a piece, I would commit it. To access various sections of the code, the end-user would have to clone my repository and checkout the specific commit for post #3.

Is there a better way to do this? I could also do something like zip up the project from before any changes for the blog post and put it at the top of the post, and not make use of git at all. As yet another alternative, I could make a bunch of different folders in the repository, each one named for a blog post, and each having a full copy of the project up until the point of that blog post.

What do you think the best way to provide code via a tutorial site would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use branches or tags in github to achieve this.

```
git checkout -b Tutorial_3 
...do some work here...
git commit -a -m "Tutorial 3 Code"
git push origin Tutorial_3
```

Reader:

```
git clone YOUR_REPOSITORY.git
cd YOUR_REPOSITORY
git fetch
git checkout Tutorial_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's how my [PHP tutorial works](http://ilovephp.jondh.me.uk/). I wrote the tutorial code first, in an iterative and organic fashion, and then wrote the text around it. The great thing is that when I have made updates to the tutorial code, I can regenerate the whole tutorial with a few console scripts.

The advantage of this approach is that I have been able to render each set of changes in HTML diffs. In order to make a change to the tutorial code, I rebase a change in, and then force-push to the remote. I use branches to maintain different versions, which is a slightly naughty misuse of Git, but it works ([see the repo here](https://github.com/halfer/php-tutorial-project)).

I maintain the [text repo](https://github.com/halfer/php-tutorial-text) in a similar fashion - branches are versions, so I can rewrite old histories at will.

If you do go down the route of rebasing, note that referencing your commits in your text is tricky, since your commit hashes are not guaranteeable. To get around this, I looked up commits using their message, like so:

```
<?php renderDiffFromComment('Add post view page') ?>
```